# Why TypeScript gives me a duplicated identifier error without reason?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, visual-studio-code

Why TypeScript gives me a duplicated identifier error without reason?

That was pretty strange. That only happen when I compiled ts:

[image]

How could that possible to get a duplicated identifier error if I only have one class?

But when I deleted 'test.js' file, everything back to normal:

[image]

but that was also not possible to use ts without compile it.

What's happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the compiled JS files in a different directory.

Now you have `class MyClass` present in both `test` files.

P.S. Naming your files `test.xx` is not a handy case, many languages have native modules named `test`, and the OS often has a command `test`

Comment: so that means, every time I compiled typescript, I need to do that? I need to delete old js file in other directory, and compile ts, then put new js file to other directory? That's too tired...

Comment: and I also want to know, they are totally difference file, one is .js and one is .ts, why do they conflict?

Comment: No, you compile the ts to js file in an `out` directory, no need to delete the js file, part of the debug start is to compile ts to js and choose the `./out/main.js` as the start file, or whatever you name the main file